# Activation error with IEventAggregator Prism

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, eventaggregator

I am using Prism in my WPF. When I add IEventAggregator as a parameter to the ViewModel constructor I get this error: *An exception of type 'Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ActivationException' occurred in Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll. 
Additional information: Activation error occurred while trying to get instance of type Object, key "CategoriesView"*

The exception is triggered in this line:

```
private void NavigateToCategoriesRadioButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.ConfigurationContentRegion, categoriesViewUri);
}
```

where categoriesViewUri is:

```
private static Uri categoriesViewUri = new Uri("/CategoriesView", UriKind.Relative);
```

This is my view model class:

```
[Export]
public class CategoriesViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private readonly IRegionManager regionManager;
    private readonly IEventAggregator eventAggregator;
    private readonly IConfigurationCategoriesService categoriesService;
    private readonly ObservableCollection<Category> categoriesCollection;
    private readonly ICollectionView categoriesView;
    private readonly DelegateCommand<object> deleteCategoryCommand;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public CategoriesViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator, IConfigurationCategoriesService categoriesService, IRegionManager regionManager)
    {    
        this.categoriesService = categoriesService;
        this.regionManager = regionManager;
        this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;

        this.deleteCategoryCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(this.DeleteCategory, this.CanDeleteCategory);

        this.categoriesCollection = new ObservableCollection<Category>(categoriesService.GetCategories());
        this.categoriesView = new ListCollectionView(this.categoriesCollection);
        this.categoriesView.CurrentChanged += (s, e) => this.deleteCategoryCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();

    }

    public ICollectionView Categories
    {
        get { return this.categoriesView; } 
    }

    public ICommand DeleteCategoryCommand
    {
        get { return this.deleteCategoryCommand; }
    }

    private void DeleteCategory(object ignored)
    {
        var category = this.categoriesView.CurrentItem as Category;
        if (category != null)
        {
            categoriesService.DeleteCategory(category);
        }
    }
    private bool CanDeleteCategory(object ignored)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

It looks like CatagoriesViewModel cannot get an instance of IEventAggregator on the constructor but this is done automatically by Prism, isn't it? In the example I have from Prism Documentation (StockTraderRI_Desktop) I don´t see anywhere where the EventAggregator is instantiated. Can anyone see what am I getting wrong? Thanks in advance

Editted:

The Navitagion item view is registerd in the CategoriesModule class:

```
[ModuleExport(typeof(CategoriesModule))]
public class CategoriesModule : IModule
{
    [Import]
    public IRegionManager regionManager;

    public void Initialize()
    {
        this.regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.ConfigurationNavigationRegion, typeof(CategoriesNavigationItemView));
    }
}
```

And CategoriesView code-behind is:

```
[Export("CategoriesView")]
public partial class CategoriesView : UserControl
{
    public CategoriesView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    [Import]
    public IRegionManager regionManager;

    [Import]
    public CategoriesViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return this.DataContext as CategoriesViewModel; }
        set { this.DataContext = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any more information in the inner exceptions? BTW - there's a delegate command without parameter, too, no need for an unused object here.

Comment: How do you know that the problem is with `IEventAggregator`? It does not stem from the error message, and I have never encountered any problem importing it. More likely culprit is that you don't have any exports for `IConfigurationCategoriesService`. Also, the error regards a `CategoriesView` and not `CategoriesViewModel`, so how do you know the problem lies there?

Comment: Hi @Grx70. I would say the problem lies there just because if I remove the IEventAggregator from the constructor of CategoriesViewModel, it works fine.

Comment: @Haukinger the inner exceptions says: {Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ActivationException: Activation error occurred while trying to get instance of type Object, key "CategoriesView"
   at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.MefServiceLocatorAdapter.DoGetInstance(Type serviceType, String key)
   at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance(Type serviceType, String key) in c:\Projects\CommonServiceLocator\main\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation\ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs:line 49}

Comment: 1) What in "categoriesViewUri"? 2) How your View registered? 3) How you obtain ViewModel for View?

Comment: @galakt I have eddited my post answering to your questions. Question 1 is answered just after "categoriesViewUri" is used. And questions 2 and 3 are answered at the end of the question, just after "Eddited:". I have added the CategoriesView code-behind so you can see how the View has the ViewModel as a property. Thansk for your help

Comment: In your edit i see how you register module, but i dont see how you register views in module. Also this kind of problems much easier to solve by debugging source code. And last: why mef, why not unity?

Comment: @galakt you are right, I have editted my post again so you can see how I register views in module. Basically the navigation-item-view is registered in the CategoriesModule.cs class but the main module is not registerd anywhere. I think maybe this is done automatically by the container?.
Why mef, why not unity? Just because the example I saw about navitagion views was done on MEF, but I have received some comments already recomending me to switch to Unity... So I am considering going to unity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue adding the following using statement:

```
using Microsoft.Practices.Prism.PubSubEvents;
```

instead of

```
using Prism.Events;
```

I also switched to Unity instead of MEF by recommendation on this site.